# Image rotation - border

Tags: image-processing

When I rotate image with my function, and rotate back, the border is really ugly. Is there a solution for that?

[image: Picture of the border I get]

Comment: I assume this is with Matlab. Please add the tag, the input image, and the code you used.

Comment: I wonder why you mention the border only, when the whole image is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using the nearest-neighbor resampling rule. You will achieve better results with bilinear or bicubic resampling.

But the best piece of advice is to avoid resampling an image several times.